# Ubuntu Chrome browser reverts?

Tags: google-chrome

It is very strange how I manage my bookmarks, update passwords, and everything is fine until some time along the line I open Chrome and everything has reverted back to how Chrome was a while ago.

Why is this happening?  I am not reverting Ubuntu nor anything else.

Should I be using Chromium instead?  But I have never had this issue in Ubuntu.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. More information is needed.

Comment: are you logged into a google account? Did you clear some cache/cookies/program data/etc?

Comment: @Esther I did not clear out anything.  I did clone my drive though but this has happened before.